# Javascript variable syntax

Tags: javascript, variables, syntax

In my code:

```
color = '31,0,0';
grd.addColorStop(0.1,'rgba(31,0,0,0.3)');
```

How do I replace 31,0,0 with the variable color? I've tried:

```
grd.addColorStop(0.1,'rgba('+color+',0.3)');
```

but got errors with that or any other combination I've tried.

Thanks!

Comment: If the first works then the second should work as well.. (*in other words, are you sure the first case works ?*)

Comment: What are the errors you're getting?

Comment: There shouldn't be any need to join an Array. Instead try grouping with `()` as in: `('rgba('+color+',0.3)')`. So you's have `grd.addColorStop(0.1, ('rgba('+color+',0.3)') );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine in my console, but maybe there is some problems with numbers and strings or something.

To avoid that, you could try this too:

```
grd.addColorStop( 0.1, ['rgba(', color, ', 0.3)'].join('') );
```